# When forwarding a DNS zone, how can i transform/alter the forwarded address?

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, bind, dns-zone

Lets say I have `zone.public.xyz.` as a publicly-accessible DNS zone, but I would like to make the private `zone.private.` zone accessible via a "proxy" DNS nameserver.

The public nameserver has an `NS` record for `zone.public.xyz`, I would then like it to forward it to a nameserver which expects it in the form of `zone.private.`, what software + configuration exists that allows me to alter the requested address before querying the forwarding server?

f.e.; someone requests `this.zone.public.xyz`, this request arrives at NS `zone.public.xyz`, which will then alter it to `this.zone.private` before forwarding it to a private DNS server.

Comment: As far as I know you cannot translate a dns record, but if it is a website you want reach, then use proxy. Besides for the host located in the private zone, does it have a public ip address? If not, then you will need todo some sort of proxy to access it directly or alternative VPN.

Comment: Don't use internal fake TLDs like `private.`